# Change algorithmicx caption name

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am trying to change the Caption name of Algorithmicx but it doesnt work. This what i include to use it.

```
%pseudocode
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algtext*{EndWhile}% Remove "end while" text
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove "end if" text
\algtext*{EndFor}
% \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Pseudocode} doesnt work
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste der Pseudocodes}
```

I am getting this:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \renewcommand{\ALG@name}
```

And also
`\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Pseudocode} doesnt work` didnt work. 
Could someone tell me whats going wrong?

---

The requested MWE. Sorry if this meight be long but thats simply my header.

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
%etwas größere schrift als default
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry} 
%definiere ränder neu
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=20mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,includefoot}
%\geometry{a4paper, portrait, left=2.5cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, includefoot}
%change font
\usepackage{helvet}
%use urls right
\usepackage{hyperref}
%include der grafiken
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%bla deutsch
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%wrapping von figuren
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%mathequark
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %for all äöü

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis} %% change name form content to inhals...
%\usepackage{cite}% citieren

\pagestyle{plain} % regular pagestyle

%command for codes inline
\providecommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

%for the code
\usepackage{listings} %code
\usepackage{xcolor}
%change the caption
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{Codeverzeichnis} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

%grapfics
\usepackage{tikz,times}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}

%pseudocode
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algtext*{EndWhile}% Remove "end while" text
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove "end if" text
\algtext*{EndFor}
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{}% doesnt work
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste der Pseudocodes}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE which shows that error, please

Comment: actually those code above is enough to create the error. I using it with KOMA scrreprt. Also deleted the aux and toc to check if something went wrong.

Comment: Add the header which already produces the error without any code or text inside of the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have tried to use the `@` character in a command name, which is not directly possible, you have to 'mask' it with the commands `\makeatletter` before using the other command and afterwards change it back to `\makeatother`, see my code below.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algtext*{EndWhile}% Remove "end while" text
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove "end if" text
\algtext*{EndFor}
\makeatletter  % Add this!!!!
 \renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Pseudocode} %doesnt work
\makeatother   % Add this also
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Liste der Pseudocodes}


\begin{document}

Some text to be written in here!

\end{document}
```

However, since I have no other information, what you intended, I can not say, whether this works at all -- there are no compilation errors, at least.

Comment: @BennX: Ok, that sounds good. I hope, it is really the solution you preferred!

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for that. I just were wondering because people use that solution without the marks i need to add now. But anyways it works.

Comment: @BennX: Perhaps they used the `\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{Pseudocode}` line (or something similar in a package (`sty`) file; in this case neither `\makeatletter` nor `\makeatother` are needed then.